# Concat database results with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web

I'm new at PHP, so if there's some kind of advice, it will be well received.

I want to concat all the results I get from a sql query to my database.

I got the code:

```
$sql = $_POST['sql']; /*sql query*/
$result = "";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
  $result = $result . ' ' . $row;
}

echo $result;
```

What I want is not a sql query that concats, but a way to concat rows with PHP.

Comment: We need to know what your data looks like in PHP

Comment: loop, echo value, echo space, repeat.

Comment: `group_concat` function with `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be:

```
select group_concat(index separator ' ')
from playerdeck;
```

This assumes that you do not care about the ordering of the values.  If you do:

```
select group_concat(index order by index separator ' ')
from playerdeck;
```

Comment: This works, but I don't want to but the concat in the sql query

Comment: ... but you should (unless there is a reason that you haven't told us).